# logstash drop filter only if included in list

Tags: logstash

Is it possible to filter log events that are from a specific group?

For example, I want to only drop events that are not in the list: ["a","b"]

```
filter {
  if !["a","b"].include? [event_name] {
    drop {}
  }
}
```

Something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logstash conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html#conditionals) support the following operators:

> equality: `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`
>
> regexp: `=~`, `!~`
>
> inclusion: `in`, `not in`

Along with some logical operators:

> `and`, `or`, `nand`, `xor`
>
> unary `!`

It sounds like you want `not in`:

```
if [event_name] not in ["a", "b"] {
    drop {}
}
```